# generate next color randomly if the color is still available

Tags: android, random

I m working on an app for android and I'm struggling at some points. One of them would be to chose the next color (out of four) but keeping in mind, that the color chosen, could be empty already, in this case the next of the four colors shall be chosen

I have two ways of doing it, but one of them is way too much code and the other one is causing a crash (I guess that happens because it can end up in an endless loop)

Thanks in advance

```
public void nextColor(Canvas canvas) {
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int theNextColor = rnd.nextInt(4);
    switch (theNextColor) {
    case 0:
        if (!blue.isEmpty()) {
            currentPaint = paintBlue;
        } else
            nextColor(canvas);

    case 1:
        if (!grey.isEmpty()) {
            currentPaint = paintGray;
        } else
            nextColor(canvas);
    case 2:
        if (!gold.isEmpty()) {
            currentPaint = paintGold;
        } else
            nextColor(canvas);
    case 3:
        if (!red.isEmpty()) {
            currentPaint = paintRed;
        } else
            nextColor(canvas);
    }
```

Comment: When it crashes post what the logcat shows. You haven't shown enough code for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if all four colors are chosen?

Regardless, this doesn't seem to be a situation where a recursive call is required. Try something like the following:

```
public void nextColor(Canvas canvas) {
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int theNextColor;
    boolean colorFound = false;

    while (!colorFound) {
       theNextColor = rnd.nextInt(4);
       if (theNextColor == 0) {
         currentPaint = paintBlue;
         colorFound = true;
       } else if (theNextColor == 1) {
         currentPaint = paintGray;
         colorFound = true;
       } else if (theNextColor == 2) {
         currentPaint = paintGold;
         colorFound = true;
       } else if (theNextColor == 3) {
         currentPaint = paintRed;
         colorFound = true;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sahhhm. Thanks for your answer.
Now I struggle finding the right position where to call this method. 

if I call it on the onDraw() method the color will be changing each time the the canvas refreshes(several times a second)

Comment: well when exactly do you want to choose a new color? you're not being very specific...

Comment: I solved it with a completely different way. I Created two arrays, one with the objects and one with a number suiting to the objekts colors. This way Only the colors that my objekts have can be chosen as the nextcolor.